# C# Serialization not serializing datatype datetime, only strings

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have a XSD that I used to create my class. When I get the XML output, all my datetime datetypes are not serialized. I'm not getting any errors when serializing. I used the ShipDate for the samples. I don't know if the Schema Tool is adding some properties that are affecting the process. For example, ShipDateSpecified with XMLIgnoreAttribute.

thanks in advance

c#

```
shipHdr.TradingPartnerId = "000ALLTESTID";
shipHdr.ShipmentIdentification = "321654987";
shipHdr.ShipDate = Convert.ToDateTime("2016-03-23");
shipHdr.CarrierProNumber = "895934589485948353";
shipHdr.AppointmentNumber = "24601";
```

Shipment Class

```
private System.DateTime shipDateField;
private bool shipDateFieldSpecified;

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType="date")]
public System.DateTime ShipDate {
    get {
        return this.shipDateField;
    }
    set {
        this.shipDateField = value;
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
public bool ShipDateSpecified {
    get {
        return this.shipDateFieldSpecified;
    }
    set {
        this.shipDateFieldSpecified = value;
    }
}
```

XML Output

```
 <ShipmentHeader>
      <TradingPartnerId>000ALLTESTID</TradingPartnerId>
      <ShipmentIdentification>321654987</ShipmentIdentification>
      <CarrierProNumber>895934589485948353</CarrierProNumber>
      <AppointmentNumber>24601</AppointmentNumber>
  </ShipmentHeader>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to manually set `ShipDateSpecified`. The XSD probably specifies that this is an optional element.

The `XmlSerializer` secretly checks for a `<ElementName>Specified` property before it attempts to serialize `<ElementName>`.

If you always specify a `ShipDate` you can simply remove the `ShipDateSpecified` property.

Comment: For the relevant documentation, see [XmlSerializer Class: Controlling Generated XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) and look for *propertyNameSpecified*.

Comment: thanks first of all , just curious, is this a normal behavior, checking  the <ElementName>Specified ???

Comment: This is default `XmlSerializer` behavior, but it does pollute the class in my opinion. It would look nicer to allow the nullable `DateTime?` type, but you still need a way to tell the serializer whether to write a `null` value or omit the element as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need an element? If you mark it as an attribute it will be serialized.

```
[XmlAttribute(DataType = "date")]
public System.DateTime ShipDate { get; set; }
```